# c# method in managed c++

Tags: c#, memory, managed-c++

I'm creating a c# dll library to scan process memory.
I have static method:

```
int searchASCII(int pid, SByte[] text, int pos)
        {
            ReadProcessApi RApi = new ReadProcessApi(pid, pos);
            return RApi.ASCIIScan(text);
        }
```

and want to make it usable in Visual C++ Managed.
Which type should be used for text param, if I want to call method like this in c++:
`searchASCII((int)pid, (char[])text, (int)position)` ?

In current scenario I get error:

```
"cannot convert parameter from 'char [6]' to 'cli::array<Type,dimension> ^' "
```

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179270/pass-c-string-to-c-and-pass-c-result-string-char-whatever-to-c)

Comment: That post is the wrong way around.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a C# function in C++\CLI you will need use the same types.  An array in C# is actually a `cli::array<T,d>` in C++\CLI.  You will not just be able to cast a C++ `char[]` to a `cli:array<T,d>`.  I would take a look at the native\managed [interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbz07712.aspx) on MSDN.

To call the function from C++\CLI you will have to create an array like this:

```
cli::array<System::SByte> ^text = gcnew cli::array<System::SByte>(/* some_size */);
```

Comment: It is C++/CLI, MC++ is a different language that doesn't have array<>.