# Return A String From A C# COM Component Method

Tags: c#, com

I have a C# Class Library which is COM visible and being called from a Visual Studio 6 application. One of the methods needs to return a string. I have tried this two ways:

```
public void GetString(out string sText)
{
    sText = MemberStringVariable;
}
```

When I call the above from VC6 I get an exception thrown.

```
public string GetString()
{
    return MemberStringVariable;
}
```

When I call the above (taking a BSTR* as parameter) I get a NULL pointer back.

What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: The 2nd way is correct.  Getting a null BSTR* would indicate that MemberStringVariable is simply unassigned.  Use the debugger in mixed mode so you can set a breakpoint in the C# code.

Answer (score 0):

Your second method:

```
public string GetString() { return MemberStringVariable; }
```

Should work. I do it all the time.
The type you get in C++ is _bstr_t as defined in comutil.h

Comment: It's not though, it's a NULL BSTR* pointer I get back. Do I need to allocate the string on the client end? This would seem odd as I would expect it to be allocated the other end. Afterall I have no idea how long the string would be.

Comment: @Joonster: can you generate the tlb with tlbexport and post the signature (using OLEView)? The signature of my methods are like `[id(0x60020007)] HRESULT get_Stuff([in] BSTR arg1, [out, retval] BSTR* pRetVal);`

Comment: Also, you need to make sure your dll is properly registered with COM

Comment: And that you don't have any incompability between 32 and 64 bits

Comment: Perhaps this is the issue. The class library is built on a 64 bit machine. The configuration is "Any CPU" though. The client app is 32-bit. Is this the problem?

Comment: @Jonnster: Try using the x86 configuration. I don't think this is the issue, but it doesn't hurt to try. It would help if you could pull out the idl from the C# dll with tlbexp.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2179270/845279) question and answer. I'm doubtful you can just return a `string` to the native code.

Comment: That's actually the other way round though. Return string from C++ to C#

Comment: I was thinking you can do the same thing, pass a buffer from C++ code to C# and the buffer can be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, it's been a while since I did COM interop, but I seem to recall you may need to use the `MarshalAsAttribute` on your method's return value.

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bstr)]
public string GetString() 
{ 
    return MemberStringVariable; 
}
```

For more examples, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.100).aspx.

Comment: Thanks. That looked promising but it actually made no difference.