# Returing a string whose length is unknown a priori from C++ called from C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, string, parameter-passing

I have searched far and wide for an answer to my question, and all the solutions are not acceptable, not applicable, and/or confusing.

I am needing to return a string from a function implemented in `C++` back to the calling code in `C#`.

The returned string needs to be returned as a **parameter** rather than a return value since I need to pass/return multiple strings for some functions. The length of the string varies, so I can't just allocate a buffer, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: **The solution posted and mentioned by Justin and/or others is NOT a solution for my use case.  As I stated in the question, I do not know the size of the string prior to making the call to the C++ code.  I can't pre-allocate a StringBuffer and pass it to the C++ code.**

Comment: Please add the function declaration.

Comment: Managed C++ or Native C++?

Comment: See [this accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179603/265575).

Comment: Where is the memory for the string allocated? By the caller or by the callee?

Comment: @Matthew: Clearly by the callee, because the caller doesn't know the right size.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not necessarily. The caller could pass the length as a different parameter.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: The caller can't pass the length, because it doesn't know the length.  I suppose there could be a separate function to find out the required length (WinAPI does this), but when there's a ready-made solution in `BSTR`, why complicate matters?

Comment: @BenVoigt Aye, fair point.

Comment: Justin, the accepted answer involves pre-allocating a buffer, which I said was not possible since I don't know what the required size will be prior to calling the C++ buffer.

Comment: The solution posted in "Pass C# string to C++ and pass C++ result (string, char*.. whatever)" involves a buffer passed into the C++ DLL.  That is NOT a solution to what I was asking.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to declare the parameter as `ref IntPtr`. So:

```
static extern void DoSomething(ref IntPtr returnedString);
```

So you call it and get a string with:

```
IntPtr pstr;
DoSomething(ref pstr);
string theString = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(pstr);
```

However, it's important to remember that the returned pointer was allocated by your C++ code. If you want it to be deallocated, you'll need to call the C++ code to do it.

You might also want to look at `Marshal.PtrToStringAuto`, and other similar functions.

Note also that this copies the data from the pointer to the string. If you want to refer to the string in place, you'll have to play with `IntPtr` and the `Marshal` class, or delve into the wonderful world of unsafe code and pointers.

Comment: `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` is good if you have to communicate with a binary blob.  It's never a good choice if you have control of both sides.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Understood. From the Q, I figured he didn't have control.

Comment: What does the C++ prototype look like? Is it: void DoSomething(int* returnedString); ? The C++ code is Native, not managed.

Comment: @Stephenosella: The C++ prototype would be `void DoSomething(char* returnedString);` Or, if you're returning Unicode strings: `TCHAR * returnedString);`

Comment: So something like:

std::string str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
returnedString = new char[str.length() + 1];
str.copy(returnedString, str.length() - 1, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Jim Michel's answer, I would create a helper function, like

```
String FromCppString(IntPtr a_Pointer)
{
    String result = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(a_Pointer);
    FreeCppString(a_Pointer);
    return result;
}
```

where `FreeCppString` is another function exported from C++, freeing the string properly. The original c++ function will just allocate as many strings as necessary and put them into parameters. The C# function will use FromCppString() to extract them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the portable (multi-compiler multi-language) string provided by the platform for the express purpose of passing strings between components implemented in different languages -- `BSTR`.

In C++, you use `SysAllocString` or `SysAllocStringLen`.  P/invoke already knows how to deal with these (convert to .NET string and call `SysFreeString`) as long as you use the right signature.

```
extern static void DoSomething([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] out String returnedString);
```

And then simply call it:

```
string theString;
DoSomething(out theString);
```

That's it, no special conversions or cleanup necessary, since p/invoke took care of it.

For more information, read [this MSDN page on string handling in p/invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9ts558h.aspx)

NOTE: I guess none of the examples in the link are *exactly* this case, so here's the C++ prototype

```
void DoSomething(__out BSTR *s);
```

Comment: What does the C++ prototype look like?  Is it: void DoSomething(char** returnedString); ?  The C++ code is Native.

Comment: @Stephenosella: `SysAllocString` and `SysFreeString` are native functions available when you `#include <windows.h>`.  You can either use Unicode, or `SysAllocStringByteLen` and `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.AnsiBStr)]`